# Grafana - Worldmap open a webpage when threshold is clicked

Tags: leaflet, grafana, rworldmap

I use the worldmap and I want to open `"www.google.com"` when I click in the treshold, is it possible ?,

I tried to modify Leaflet library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this, but you can create a workaround with clickevents.

Look what html-id has you map.

```
$('#mapid_2').on('click',function(){
    $('.leaflet-popup').on('click',function(e){
        window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');
    });
})
```

Comment: i'me a noob in javascript, can you said which file i need to modify

Comment: Then this is difficult. I don't kow how grafanas filesystem looks like. Maybe you find a `index.html` file, there you can add at the end (above </body> ) `<script>code from above</script>'